# How to Navigateback from Xamarin.Forms Prism Popup

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

Xamarin.forms using Prism Navigation back is not working in below scenario :

1. App.xaml.cs  in `OnInitialized` `NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(LoginView));`
2. In LoginViewModel once login I am navigating to MainPage `await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("MainPage", UriKind.Relative),useModalNavigation:true, animated: false);`
3. MainPaga has a Button once I click in Button it will Popup setting Page navigation Popup like : `await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("SettingView", UriKind.Relative), useModalNavigation: true, animated: false);`
4. SettingView(Popup) has a Button(LogOut) once I click on Button(LogOut) it has to go back in LoginView here is the code navigating back.

   ```
                   await _navigationService.ClearPopupStackAsync(animated: false);
               await _navigationService.GoBackAsync(useModalNavigation: true, animated: false);
   ```

first I am Clearing Popup then navigating back, but it wont navigate back to LoginView?

Comment: If you ClearPopupStackAsync, won't all pages be popped from the stack? So there's no LoginView to come back to.

Comment: then how would I go back from Popup page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PRISM and want to 'clear' the current stack.
You better use the explicit uri navigation.
Meaning the code behind the logout button should look like this

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/LoginView");
```

By adding the / at the beginning of the URI, the current stack will be cleared.

Comment: Hi @Depechie, Thank you for you reply it is work but only problem is it is under NavigationPage so showing TopBar which is problem I want it like Modal, can we achieve this?

Comment: In the constructor of the LoginView you could put: NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); to hide the navigation bar.

Comment: I am doing like this                     await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/LoginView", param,useModalNavigation:true);

Comment: Yep and that is correct, but still if you use a NavigationPage - the top bar will be shown, until you disable it with the NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); method.

Comment: First time it wont show TopBar I don't know but once I do like above then it showing me TopBar.

Comment: Hmm  weird, it should work like that. Maybe you can adjust your code and add more code in the question? Not sure why it's failing...

Comment: I am creating GitHub repository once it done upload here so that you can check it out what is going wrong! meanwhile I am accepting your answer thank you very much for you quick support.

Comment: I also found that this works ... `await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/LoginPage");` without the NavigationPage.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use absolute uri to set Loginpage as Mainpage after user confirm to logout like this

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(new System.Uri("/LoginPage",System.UriKind.Absolute));
```